# how to replace ' with " inside a String

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a String containing: 'abc' 'abc' 'abc'.
How can i use replaceAll, to produce: "abc" "abc" "abc" ?

I tried using

```
StringA=StringA.replaceAll(''','"');
```

Comment: `StringA=StringA.replaceAll("'","\"");`

Comment: Your example won't compile. Simple googling would give you the answer you need. Why bother to asking the question here? I am talking that this is silly question, it is not. But you may get the answer much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to replace every occurrence of a **char** by another char is [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29).

The char literal for a single quote is `'\''` (the single quote must be escaped, so that it's not interpreted as the end of the char literal).

So you want

```
s = s.replace('\'', '"');
```

`replaceAll()`, suggested by many other answers, replaces substrings matching a regexp by another substring. It's less appropriate than the method replacing a single char by another one.

Side note: please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter. Only class names start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: So what? BTW, it's not exactly the same, since mine doesn't recommend escaping the double quote, explains why the single quote must be escaped, suggests respecting naming conventions, and provides a link to the javadoc. If you're concerned that I borrowed your idea, I didn't. Actually, I commented about it  before you posted your answer, in unknown's answer, in hope that he would fix his answer. But unknown didn't catch my comment, so I posted an answer while you were posting yours.

Answer (score 3):

`StringA = StringA.replace('\'', '\"');`

Even though it's called `replace` and not `replaceAll`, what it actually does is replace all 
occurrences of one character with the other:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of
>   oldChar in this string with newChar.

This is more efficient than using the `replaceAll` version which replaces strings.

Comment: Why escape the double quote? It doesn't need to be.

Comment: You're right, but it's common to do that, since it's a special character. It's considered a better practice to escape the double quotes in a single quotation as well, even though, as you correctly mention, it isn't mandatory.

Comment: Considered by who? I find it clutters the code and makes it less readable.

Comment: Well, to each his own. However, I don't really see how a single backslash character "clutters" code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\` before **double quote**.

```
StringA = StringA.replaceAll("'","\"");
```

Comment: It's replace, not replaceAll. replaceAll takes two strings as argument, and uses a regexp. And why use a regexp to replace a single char by another one, since a dedicated method exists for that (and is obviously faster).

Comment: first string is `'` (single quote) and second string is `"`(double quote).

Comment: Your original answer took chars as arguments, but used the wrong method name.

Comment: I have updated it. It can not be character. ty for pointing out.